# Share the Raspberry Pi date and time with esp8266 on the same network

Tags: rtc

I would like to share the time and date on my Raspberry Pi, which is functioning as a MQTT server, with the ESP8266 units on my network. This is so I do not have to attach RTC boards to each one. I could use a NTP get program on each ESP-8266, but getting a time connection to NTP is sometimes not possible. My system is attached to the internet, and the raspberry pi is always on. If I lose power, then everything turns off, and that's ok. When the power comes back on, everything reboots automatically.  Thanks for your help.
Don M

Comment: I'm not quite there with this one - what is it you're trying to find out?